# How do I retrieve SSIS package logging from ASP NET after/during execution? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ssis

I am executing an SSIS package from an ASP NET web form.

How can I programmatically obtain the actually logging information, rather than the basic execution "Success" or "Failed" execution results when I am using the execution procedure below?

```
myPackage = app.LoadPackage(packageLocation, null);
myPackage.Execute()
```

I am aware of the basic package execution result (shown below) but I want more details, similar to the log files obtainable through SSIS debugging.

```
 DTSExecResult myResult = myPackage.Execute();
 lblStatus.Text = "Package result: " + myResult.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using some of the logging methods available to the SSIS package itself in [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.aspx).

Specifically you should be able to reference [`DtsContainer.LogEntryInfos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.logentryinfos.aspx) for the package in order to view all of the associated log entries. In your case this woudl be `deletePkg`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to get it in real time, but you are probably logging to either a table or a file, so you can retrieve the log either with a SQL query to the table, or a filestream to the file.